# C# how to use OpenCV to remove noise of a captcha?

Tags: c#, image, opencv, image-processing, captcha

I'm trying to learn how to remove noise of a captcha image. I started trying to find patterns in the images.

1) The background are always orange:

[image: captcha 1] [image: captcha 2] [image: captcha 3]

2) The font are aways the same and aways are in the same size.

[image: captcha 4]

Now its time to try to remove the noise, but in my searches I coudnt understand how to remove noise effectively with the captchas I have.

I'm familiar with C# and I was reading about OpenCV, how can I use it to remove the noise in the images I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load the image, convert to grayscale, and adaptive threshold.
2. **Isolate desired characters.** Perform morphological opening to remove the salt & pepper noise.
3. **Remove small noise.** Find contours and filter using contour area.
4. **Invert image.** The reason we invert the image is because when performing OCR, we want the *desired text in black with the background in white.*

---

Here's a visualization of each step:

Binary image

[image]

Morph opening + contour area filtering

[image]

Invert image for result

[image]

Here's the output with the other images

[image]
[image]

I implemented this appraoch in python but you can adapt the same strategy into C#

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, adaptive threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,3)

# Morph open
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

# Remove noise by filtering using contour area
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 10:
        cv2.drawContours(opening, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Invert image for result
result = 255 - opening

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Nathancy, it was very detailed and helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For images like these which are very binary, I would suggest OpenCV's morphological transformations. [See here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) for a description of the different types.
This transformation is probably what you'd want to do to remove the noise, although it will slightly change the shape of your letters:

[image: morphological opening]

This is called "opening" and it erodes white space (completely erasing small little flecks like your noise) then it'll dilate the white space that remains, so larger pieces will stay about the same size. Try [thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) your image and then use opening with different size kernels to see which one works the best.

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#morphologyex) is the documentation on the function you'll need for morphological opening.